# Angular 2 different base route

Tags: angular

I would like to change my angular2 base route to something other than `/`.

For instance,

```
http:// localhost:27149/home
```

to

```
http:// localhost:27149/index.html#/home
```

or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Who upvoted this ?:D

Comment: Are you using webpack ? or what ?

Comment: yes Webpack but I guess it's more about routing provider then webpack

Comment: Well you can somewhat achieve this by changing the base href in index file, but uhmm... I wouldn't :D

Comment: this what I tried first before posting this question ! I'm talking about angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we just need to add  **{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }**

in the angular 2 bootstrap

of course we need to load those modules

**import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";**

hope this help